# 'LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors

Tags: spring-cloud, reactive, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?
I get this warning by simply adding 'spring-cloud-loadbalancer' in the classpath.

Logs:

```
022-09-20 14:38:15,199 INFO  [main] o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker: Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-09-20 14:38:15,201 INFO  [main] o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker: Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration$ReactorDeferringLoadBalancerFilterConfig' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration$ReactorDeferringLoadBalancerFilterConfig] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-09-20 14:38:15,206 INFO  [main] o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker: Bean 'reactorDeferringLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.DeferringLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

Comment: It's just a warning. There's no need to address this.